# Passing parameter in a BigQuery Script

Tags: shell, google-bigquery, google-cloud-shell

I want to pass argument to a BigQuery script in shell, here is the example of script I wrote

```
#!/bin/bash
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false --destination_table=abc   --append 'select * from `xyz.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS` union all Select * from `def.VIEWS`) where table_name = "$1"'
```

when I run this script and pass the argument, I do not get any errors but no row is appended to the table. whereas when i specify the table_name as rty that row is appended to the table. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run the script you'll get a prompt like:

```sh
Waiting on <BIGQUERY_JOB_ID> ... (0s) Current status: DONE
```

You can inspect the job in many ways, including the `bq`tool:

```sh
bq show -j --format=prettyjson <BIGQUERY_JOB_ID>
```

If you have `jq` installed (`sudo apt install jq`) you can get just the translated query with:

```sh
bq show -j --format=prettyjson <BIGQUERY_JOB_ID> | jq '.configuration.query.query'
```

which will get you something similar to:

```sql
select * from xyz.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS where table_name = \"$1\"
```

As you can see the variable is not correctly escaped so no table matches the `WHERE` filter. To avoid this you can enclose the query in double quotes and the variable in single ones like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
bq query \
--use_legacy_sql=false \
--destination_table=xyz.abc \
--append \
"select * from xyz.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS where table_name='$1'"
```

You can get the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS: command not found` error if using back-ticks. You can omit or escape them with a backslash:

```sh
"select * from \`xyz\`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS where table_name='$1'"
```

Comment: When I update the query with double quotes, the argument is getting passed in the query but i am getting another error. saying that the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS: command not found

Comment: Ah, this happens because of the back-ticks. I edited the answer with a possible way to escape them.